# How do I use the Tor Browser for Android without Tor?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, android

I use the [Tor Browser for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.torproject.torbrowser&hl=en_US) and it always takes long at startup since it has to start the Tor daemon first and I don't want to wait that long so I'd rather just disable the Tor daemon and configure it to use the already running Orbot.

How would I do this? It's easy on desktop but I have no idea on android.

Answer (score 0):

Edited:

> I'd rather just disable the Tor daemon and configure it to use the
>   already running Orbot.

That's not possible because the current version of Tor Browser can't be divorced from the Tor daemon. Your only option is to go back to using Orfox with Orbot but there's no word yet on how long that will continue to be supported by the Tor Project team.

Comment: I know how to use other browsers with Tor. That's not what I'm asking. Read the post again.